# Debian networking stopped working after cloning VM image (virtualbox)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, virtualization, debian

After I cloned a VirtualBox VM image, either original nor cloned Debian 6 (squeeze) image have networking works anymore.

I've read A TON of articles online describing modifying the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and `/etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules` files but none of those "fixes" worked for me.

(Apparently this is a "feature" of UDEV that causes all kinds of problems if you are using Debian/Ubuntu in a virtualized environment for development and want to clone images because it changes your MAC address of your virtual NIC).

Can someone please described exactly what I need to do in order to have networking working again in my VM debian images. Thanks

***Note***: networking stopped in BOTH (all) debian virtual images now. Essentially, [1](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/660) how do I fix my MAC address since I don't even know what MAC address should now be used, [2] how do I prevent this from happening in the future when I clone VM images?

**UPDATE**:  My problem [was filed as a bug](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/660) with both VirtualBox and VMWare but both companies closed the tickets stating this is a "feature" of Debian.  Some people suggests ways to fix the problem but none have worked.

Comment: Happens when cloning fedora machines too as of Virtualbox 4.2.8. I thought updating Virtualbox would fix the dns but it doesn't. I have yet to try @raydos answer because doing the same operation on fedora is different.

Comment: The MAC address of your virtual nettwork cards can be found and changed in the settings of your virtual machine. For virtualbox, shut down the guest, right click the guest and go into the network settings.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are still tracking this problem but, I have encountered this problem too and the solution that works consistently for me when I do clone a Debian guest is as follows:

1. Prior to cloning, shutdown the VM to be cloned.
2. Clone the VM (make sure you select "Reinitialize the MAC address of all network cards")
3. Boot the clone VM and edit the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` as root.  Remove all references to interfaces.  These will be rebuild automatically the next time you boot.

Comment: Excellent, fixed my problem.

Comment: With Debian Jessie the directory `/etc/udev/rules.d` is empty.